# Tomcat web application only works after I explicitly start it in the /manager page

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, tomcat7

I have this web application deployed in tomcat.  Although it doesn't automatically start after  the machine restarts and everything loads up.  It only works when I go to the manager page and start it from there or restart the tomcat service.

I get the Error Startlistener and the Severe message:

> The web application [web application] registered the JDBC driver
>   [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when
>   the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC
>   Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Has anyone experienced this same type of issue?  I've ran out of debugging ideas.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you have a JDBC driver which causes memory leak an make the Tomcat throw that error. Tomcat 7 has `Memory Leak` detection and prevention mechanism which warn you if you have driver that has been registered on start-up but did not un-register after termination. Two suggestions:

1. Un-register the driver explicitly:

   ```
   // Example: DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306");
   java.sql.Driver mySqlDriver = DriverManager.getDriver("YOUR DRIVER");
   DriverManager.deregisterDriver(mySqlDriver);
   ```
2. Use [JDBC connection pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) on Tomcat

I would personally prefer the `connection pool`. Also take a look at [Apache Tomcat 7: Error listenerStart msg](http://www.vegaasen.com/blog/?p=184) regarding your listenerStart problem.